# What to do if I want to answer my own "non-constructive" closed question?

Tags: discussion

My question was closed as "non-constructive", so I asked it in other place (Freenode) where I got the answer which I want to add to superuser.com.

What should I do?

1. Edit the question, including the answer as section of the question itself;

   1b. "Re-brand" the question to suit the answer more + include the answer into it;
2. Vote to reopen, then add the answer normally;

   2b. "Re-brand" the question and vote to reopen
3. Add the answer as comment to the question;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Re-brand to suit your answer and remove the non-constructive aspect of the question. Given that you now have an answer, that shouldn't be too hard. Otherwise, feel free to request assistance (on meta or chat).
2. Vote to re-open the question. If you're confident about your adjustments, you can also flag the question and ask for a quick reopening.
3. After the question is reopened, please post your answer just as you regularly would and mark it as the accepted solution once you feel comfortable.

Comment: (Reopen request to [the question](http://superuser.com/questions/477234/what-are-differences-between-qemu-and-kvm-in-setup-and-configuration) seems to gained no attention. As I added the answer to the question itself, it can probably just settle in closed state)

Comment: @Vi.: Even though you've received an answer, which you found satisfactory, to your problem elsewhere, posting that answer would not resolve the non-constructive-ness of the question. So there is no reason to reopen it. You could make a canonical (CW) question+answer that deals with the differences between the two virtualization environments. But I would seriously doubt if that is worth the effort.